# OpenGL error of Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: visual-studio-emulator

Visual Studio Emulator for Android (VSEA) worked fine until I started using a video card to support an ultra-wide monitor.  I keep getting the following error after running it for a few minutes:

```
An OpenGL error has occurred:
Error packing read bufferk, ignoring
The emulator will not shut down.
```

[image]

Could anyone offer a remedy for this?

Update(2016-03-02):
It has been working fine after the video card (Zotac GeForce 8400GS) was removed, and the motherboard integrated graphics was used instead.

Comment: Have same problem, if somebody knows solution - it will be very nice

Comment: My particular case is related to a video card. The error has disappeared after I removed the video card (Zotac GeForce 8400GS).  I am using the integrated video of my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help. The OpenGL error is actually very misleading, and I believe it has nothing to do with OpenGL at all.

Whenever I see this error, I will goto Hyper-V, look at where the vhd located.

In my case it is located at:

```
C:\Users\<myname>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices
```

Just delete the .cfg and vhd associated with the affected device, and then use VS Emulator for Android to re-create it. (remember to delete it from Hyper-V before you do this)